# What article do I use before the word "order"?

Tags: articles

Which article should be used before the word "order"?

> I ask you to send me a/the order for trimmer R2 and the DB2 connector.

---

Note: The existing answer was based on a previous version of this question that mistakenly used *offer* rather than *order*.

Comment: I edited the question again so that the existing answer is not confusing for anybody reading it.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't used the word "order" in your sentence: I guess that "offer" is an error for "order".

As usual, the definite article "the" is used where the object is known information.

I would expect "an order" here. If you say "the order", this implies that the recipient already knows which order you mean: presumably you have previously discussed it.

One other point that occurs to me, (not directly what your question was about): "please send me an order for X" is something that the seller might say to a person wanting to buy something: "the order" is the formal commercial request. Is that what you meant? If this is the buyer asking for goods, don't use "the order for", just "please send me X"

**Edit**: Chiara has explained that it was "order" that was the error, not "offer". The argument is unchanged: if you have already discussed the matter with the seller, you might say "the offer", but otherwise "an offer".

Actually, "offer" is still not the best word: I would only use it if the seller has a "special offer" - a temporary reduction in price or addition of benefit. I can't think of a suitable word: I would just say "please send me the prices and details">

Comment: I`m so sorry. I felt tired and misprinted the question. I did mean the word "offer" in the sentence.

Comment: I ask the seller to send me his offer with prices for the required details.